# Why does NCurses fails with not being able to free the pointer?

Tags: c++, ncurses

So I was following the ncurses guide from https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/helloworld.html
and when i try to run the compiled code it exits with Abort trap: 6
the code that I have written

```
#include <ncurses.h> //Including the NCurses library

int main(){
    initscr();       // Initializing the NCurses
    printw("Hello world"); // Printing Hello world
    refresh();             // Displaying the Window's content on terminal
    getch();               // Pausing the program until a key is pressed
    endwin();              // Freeing the Terminal from NCurses
    return 0;
}
```

the program's Error

```
SomeTry(17615,0x118bf35c0) malloc: *** error for object 0xf000000000000000: pointer being freed was not allocated
SomeTry(17615,0x118bf35c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

lldb's output:

```
SomeTry(17433,0x10010b5c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x14: pointer being freed was not allocated
SomeTry(17433,0x10010b5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Process 17433 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00007fff579c82c6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
->  0x7fff579c82c6 <+10>: jae    0x7fff579c82d0            ; <+20>
    0x7fff579c82c8 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff579c82cb <+15>: jmp    0x7fff579c2457            ; cerror_nocancel
    0x7fff579c82d0 <+20>: retq   
Target 0: (SomeTry) stopped.
```

I would be thankful for any helps given about this error

Stuff I've tried:

```
removing printw and refresh and getch from the code and compiling and
running it still no luck and also only kept initscr in the main function
and I think it's because of initscr not being able to allocate the memory 
but why and how I can resolve them is the question.
```

Software that i use:

```
cmake 3.18.2
llvm Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
macOS 10.14.5
ncurses 6.1 from conan-center
conan package manager 1.28.1
```

Comment: Does their [original example code](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/printw.html) work for you?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The code doesn't work. i'm going to add more information in my post.

Comment: The version of `ncurses` may play a part in it too (even though I don't think it does) - so please include the version you use to make the question more complete.

Comment: The version of ncurses could be relevant only if (for example) OP is mixing libraries from different development systems.   Apple's copy of ncurses 5.7 hasn't changed for more than ten years.

Comment: @ThomasDickey and TedLyngmo Thanks, The Problem was from ncurses 6.1 installing ncurses 6.2 solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

If Anyone has the same problem, Check the Version that you're trying to install from conan. ncurses 6.1 has this issue and upgrading it to ncurses 6.2 fixed it